# Why are parentheses required for assignment of a tuple to an annotated variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, syntax-error, iterable-unpacking

When I have a line that looks like this:

```
t: Tuple[int, int] = 0, 1
```

… I get a `SyntaxError`, but when I do this:

```
t = 0, 1
t: Tuple[int, int] = (0, 1)
```

… it's valid.

Is this intentional? Is there an ambiguity in the parse tree with a type specifier and no parens?

Comment: I don't know the rationale, but this is explicitly called out in the docs and the original PEP.

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#annotated-assignment-statements): "The difference from normal Assignment statements is that only single target and only *single right hand side value* is allowed."

Comment: [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#where-annotations-aren-t-allowed): "Only single assignment targets and *single right hand side values* are allowed."

Answer (score 0):

It is intentional. In the original proposal for variable annotations on the python-ideas mailing list, Guido van Rossum [writes](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2016-August/041294.html):

```
Third, there's an annoying thing with tuples/commas here. On the one
hand, in a function declaration, we may see (a: int = 0, b: str = '').
On the other hand, in an assignment, we may see

a, b = 0, ''

Suppose we wanted to add types to the latter. Would we write this as

a, b: int, str = 0, ''

or as

a: int, b: str = 0, ''

??? Personally I think neither is acceptable, and we should just write it as

a: int = 0
b: str = ''

but this is a slight step back from

a, b = 0, ''   # type: (int, str)
```

… and then, in the relevant GitHub [issue](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/258):

> #### Multiple types/variables
>
> An obvious question is whether to allow combining type declarations
>   with tuple unpacking (e.g. `a, b, c = x`). This leads to (real or
>   perceived) ambiguity, and I propose *not* to support this. If there's a
>   type annotation there can only be one variable to its left, and one
>   value to its right. **This still allows tuple *packing* (just put the
>   tuple in parentheses)** but it disallows tuple *unpacking*. (It's been
>   proposed to allow multiple parenthesized variable names, or types
>   inside parentheses, but none of these look attractive to me.)